# Where is the memory address of a c/c++ pointer held?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system

If I do the following:

```
int i, *p = &i;
int **p2p = &p;
```

I get the address of i (on the stack) and pass it to p, I then get the address of p (on the stack) and pass that to p2p.

My question is, we know the value of `i` is kept in the memory address `p` and so forth but how does the operating system know where that address is? I suppose their addresses are being kept organized in the stack. Is each declared variable (identifier) treated like an offset from the current position of the stack? What about global variables, how does the operating system and/or the compiler deal with addressing these during execution? How does the OS and the compiler work to 'remember' the addresses of each identifier without using memory? Are all variables just entered (pushed) in-order into the stack and their names are replaced with their offsets? if so, what about conditional code that can change the order of declaration?

Comment: Modern operating systems use [Virtual Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)

Comment: in the lower level there is no concept of variables. It is an abstraction we made to make our lives easier when programming.

Comment: RageD: Aside from not being an answer to the question, it's also not true. Just because the major desktop OS use virtual memory doesn't make this blanket statement (modern <=> VM) more valid. As for the question: Variables and identifiers are for the programmer's convenience. The CPU only sees memory addresses and the values they contain.

Comment: "Is each declared variable (identifier) treated like an offset from the current position of the stack? " -- Yes, for stack variables. "What about global variables" -- Read up on linkers and loaders.

Comment: "Are all variables just entered (pushed) in-order into the stack and their names are replaced with their offsets?" -- This is a bit conceptually confused. Variable names *represent* offsets on the stack; they aren't "pushed". Stack frames are added to the stack when a function called, but there's no pushing, the stack just grows  (and shrinks on return). " if so, what about conditional code that can change the order of declaration?" -- Conditional code can't change anything ... changing the conditions is like writing a separate program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, data can be stored in 4 different areas of memory, depending on its *scope* and whether it's *constant* or *variable*. I say "conceptually" because memory allocation is very platform-dependent, and the strategy can become extremely complicated in order to wring out as much efficiency as modern architectures can provide.

It's also important to realize that, with few exceptions, the OS doesn't know or care where variables reside; the CPU does.  It's the CPU that processes each operation in a program, calculates addresses, and reads and writes memory.  In fact, the OS itself is just a program, with its own variables, that the CPU executes.

In general, the *compiler* decides which *type* of memory (*e.g.* stack, heap, register) to allocate for each variable.  If it chooses a register, it also decides *which* register to allocate.  If it chooses another type of memory, it calculates the variable's *offset* from the beginning of that section of memory.  It creates an "object" file that still references these variables as offsets from the start of their sections.

Then the *linker* reads each of the object files, combines and sorts their variables into the appropriate sections, and then "fixes up" the offsets. (That's the technical term.  Really.)

#### Constant data

**What is it?**
Since this data never changes it's typically stored alongside the program itself in an area of  read-only memory.  In an embedded system, like a microwave oven, this may be in (traditionally inexpensive) ROM instead of (more expensive) RAM.  On a PC, it's a segment of RAM that's been designated as ready-only by the OS, so an attempt to write to it will cause a segmentation fault and stop the program before it "illegally" changes something it shouldn't.

**How is it accessed?**
The compiler typically references constant data as an offset from the beginning of the constant data segment.  It's the linker that knows where the segment actually resides, so it  fixes the starting address of the segment.

#### Global and static data

**What is it?**
This data must be available throughout the entire life of the running program, so it must reside on a "heap" of memory that's been allocated to the program.  Since the data can change, the heap cannot reside in read-only memory as does constant data; it *must* reside in writable RAM.

**How is it accessed?**
The CPU accesses global and static data in the same way as constant data: it's referenced as an offset from the start of the heap, with the heap's starting address fixed by the linker.

#### Local data

**What is it?**
These are variables that exist only while an enclosing function is active.  They reside in RAM that is allocated dynamically and then returned to the system immediately when the function exits.  Conceptually, they're allocated from a "stack" that grows as functions are called and create variables; it shrinks as each function returns.  The stack also holds the "return address" for each function call:  the CPU records its current location in the program and "pushes" that address onto the stack before it calls a function; then, when the function returns, it "pops" the address off the stack so it can resume from wherever it was before the function call.  But again, the actual implementation depends on the architecture; the important thing is to remember that a function's local data becomes invalid, and should therefore never be referenced, after the function returns.

**How is it accessed?**
Local data is accessed by its offset from the beginning of the stack.  The compiler knows the next available stack address when it enters a function, and ignoring some esoteric cases, it also knows how much memory it needs for local variables, so it moves the "stack pointer" to skip over that memory.  It then references each local variable by calculating its address within the stack.

#### Registers

**What are they?**
A register is a small area of memory within the CPU itself.  All calculations occur within registers, and register operations are very fast.  The CPU contains a relatively small number of registers, so they're a limited resource.

**How are they accessed?**
The CPU can access registers directly, which makes register operations very quick.  The compiler may choose to allocate a register to a variable as an optimization, so it won't need to wait while it fetches or writes the data to RAM.  Generally, only local data is assigned to registers.  For example, a loop counter may reside in a register, and the stack pointer is itself a register.

> **The answer to your question:**
>   When you declare a variable on the stack, the compiler calculates its size and assigns memory for it, beginning at the next available location on the stack.  Let's look at your example, making the following assumptions:
>   1.  When the function is called, `SP` is the next available address in the stack, which grows downward.
>   2.  `sizeof(int)` = 2 (just to make it different from the size of a pointer).
>   3.  `sizeof(int *)` = `sizeof(int **)` = 4 (that is, all pointers are the same size).
>   Then:
>
> ```
>     int i, *p = &i;
>     int **p2p = &p;
> ```
>
> You're declaring 3 variables:
>   `i`:       Addr = `SP`,       size = `2`,   contents = *`uninitialized`*
>   `p`:       Addr = `SP-2`,   size = `4`,   contents = `SP` *(address of `i`)*
>   `p2p`:  Addr = `SP-6`,   size = `4`,   contents = `SP-2` *(address of `p`)*

Comment: One note: if a constant identifier is defined to a literal numeric value, for instance: const int width = 640; the name width will be replaced by the compiler with the value 640. If the values is decided in run time: const int width = get_width(); then the values is stored in memory.

Answer (score 2):

I used to be an assembly language programmer, so I know the answer for the CPUs that I used to work with.  The main point is that one of the CPU's registers is used as the stack pointer, called SP (or `esp` on x86 CPUs these days).  The compiler references the variables (i, p and p2p in your case) relative to SP.  In other words, the compiler decides what the offset of each variable should be from SP, and produces machine code accordingly.

Comment: Actually the `EBP` is used, not `ESP` (or `RBP` on AMD64 architecture). `[SS:EBP + 0]` points to the saved `EBP` itself, `[SS:EBP + 4]` points to the return address, `[SS:EBP + 8]` points to the first parameter, `[SS:EBP + 12]` to the second and so on...

Answer (score 1):

The operating system is not concerned about the addresses your programs use. Whenever a system call is issued that needs to use a buffer within your address space, your program provides the address of the buffer.

Your compiler presents a stack frame for each of your functions.

```
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
```

Then, any function parameters or local variables can be addressed relative to the value of the EBP register which is then the base address of that stack frame. This is taken care of by the compiler via reference tables specific to your compiler.

Upon exiting the function, the compiler tears down the stack frame:

```
mov esp,ebp
pop ebp
```

At low level, the CPU only works with literal BYTE/WORD/DWORD/etc values and addresses (that are the same, but used differently).

A memory address that's needed is either stored in a named buffer (e.g. global var) that the compiler substitutes with its known address at compile time or in a register of the CPU (quite simplified, but still true)

Being into OS development, I'd gladly explain anything I know in more depth if you like, but that's for sure out of scope for SOF so we need to find another channel if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

> the value of i is kept in the memory address p and so forth but how does the operating system know where that address is?

The OS doesn't know nor care where the variables are.

> I suppose [variables'] addresses are being kept organized in the stack.

The stack does not organize variables' addresses. It simply contains/holds the values of the variables.

> Is each declared variable (identifier) treated like an offset from the current position of the stack?

That may indeed hold true for some local variables. However, optimization can either move variables into CPU registers or eliminate them altogether.

> What about global variables, how does the operating system and/or the compiler deal with addressing these during execution?

The compiler does not deal with the variables when the program has already been compiled. It has finished its job.

> How does the OS and the compiler work to 'remember' the addresses of each identifier without using memory?

The OS does not remember any of that. It doesn't even know anything about your program's variables. To the OS your program is just a collection of somewhat amorphous code and data. Names of variables are meaningless and rarely available in compiled programs. They are only needed for programmers and compilers. Neither the CPU nor the OS needs them.

> Are all variables just entered (pushed) in-order into the stack and their names are replaced with their offsets?

That would be a reasonable simplified model for local variables.

> if so, what about conditional code that can change the order of declaration?

That's what the compiler has to deal with. Once the program's compiled, all has been taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

as @Stochastically explained:

> The compiler references the variables (i, p and p2p in your case)
>   relative to SP. In other words, the compiler decides what the offset
>   of each variable should be from SP, and produces machine code
>   accordingly.

maybe this example explains it additionally to you. It is on amd64, thus size of pointer is 8 bytes. As you can see there are no variables, only offsets from register.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int i, *p = &i;
    int **p2p = &p;
    printf("address 0f i: %p",p);//0x7fff4d24ae8c
    return 0;
}
```

disassembly:

```
!int main(int argc, char** argv) {
main(int, char**)+0: push   %rbp
main(int, char**)+1: mov    %rsp,%rbp
main(int, char**)+4: sub    $0x30,%rsp
main(int, char**)+8: mov    %edi,-0x24(%rbp)
main(int, char**)+11: mov    %rsi,-0x30(%rbp)
!
!    int i, *p = &i;
main(int, char**)+15: lea    -0x4(%rbp),%rax
main(int, char**)+19: mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)  //8(pointer)+4(int)=12=0x10-0x4
!    int **p2p = &p;
main(int, char**)+23: lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
main(int, char**)+27: mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp) //8(pointer)
!    printf("address 0f i: %p",p);//0x7fff4d24ae8c
main(int, char**)+31: mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax //this is pointer
main(int, char**)+35: mov    %rax,%rsi //get address of variable, value would be %esi
main(int, char**)+38: mov    $0x4006fc,%edi
main(int, char**)+43: mov    $0x0,%eax
main(int, char**)+48: callq  0x4004c0 <printf@plt>
!    return 0;
main(int, char**)+53: mov    $0x0,%eax
!}
main(int, char**)()
main(int, char**)+58: leaveq 
main(int, char**)+59: retq
```